# How can I use parenthesis in a RegExp character class?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've used this code to create a regular expression in javascript

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\\(\\)]$");
```

I've also tried

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\(\)]$");
```

And I always get:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_-\(\)]$/: Range out of order in character class
```

Comment: put `-` at the last inside the char classs and you need to escape the backslash one more time.

Comment: Parenthesis are not special in a character class, representing only themselves: remove the escapes. Also, you need to *escape-the-escape* in a regular expression when written as a string (for all cases when such is desired) so that the escape is seen when read as a regular expression. Alternatively, use `//` to avoid having to escape-the-escapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put character `-` within a character class literally you need to put it at the end of other characters. because the regex engine will assume it as character range.

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_()-]
```

Also you don't need to escape the regex characters within character class!

See demo https://regex101.com/r/kG2zC4/1

Answer (score 0):

Your regex must be,

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_()-]$")
```

or

```
var reg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9_()-]$/;
```

or

```
var reg = /^[\w()-]$/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to escape the `-`

```
new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9_\\-()]$");
```